# What does commit and Start Transaction do?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

when looking in symfony2 at the DB Queries I have 18 queries. (I think it is a lot) I am only updating one records.

Anyway. I also saw that some of thoses queries are named '**COMMIT**' and '**START TRANSACTION**'. Which is not very clear what it does. Any one could explain it to me? thanks.

here an exemple of what I have with Symfony2

[image: SYMFONY2]

Comment: The 18 queries could be for multiple reasons.  If your entities are linked to many other entities and you perform an INSERT, they have to insert into multiple tables.  Also, if your entities are linked to may other entities, Symfony by default 'lazily' loads them rather than using a database JOIN.  You can always change your repository calls to explicitly use joins when you need them.

Comment: I change for a repository calls with joins entity. However still end up with 5 queries when updating a record. (I count Start transaction and Commit in the 5) Anyway will try to optimise it and might post an other question direcly related to this issue. (thanks anyway for the answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jovan's link is a better read, but in layman's terms, all queries between **START TRANSACION** and **COMMIT** are treated as a whole; meaning, if one of those queries fails then they all 'rollback' and fail.  **START TRANSACTION** simply signifies the start of the grouping, and **COMMIT** finishes it.  It's used when you logically need all of the queries to happen.

Say for instance you want to insert a new employee, and they **have** to have some permissions set. You need to insert into a *user* table and then a *user_roles* table.

Now, say you *don't* use the above, and try running the following two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO user (...);
INSERT INTO user_roles (...);
```

What if the first query works, but the second query doesn't?  You'll have a 'dangling` user without any permissions, and they'll be sitting in database limbo.

If you instead use a transaction as shown below, you can make sure that either all the queries work, or none of them work.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO user (...);
INSERT INTO user_roles (...);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: ok Jason thanks. Just one more question, What the point in using it then when there is only one query. I got in SYmfony2/Doctrine the update of a records. I have 'Start Transaction', then an 'update' query, then a 'commit' (see picture added in my question)

Comment: It's just the default the Symfony and Doctrine will wrap all logical transactions in, even if it's just one query.

Answer (score 1):

Because database transactions are very serious topic, instead of me trying to explain it here very briefly, I think it would be more beneficial to you to read this wiki article:

**[Wikipedia: Database Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)**

Comment: ok @Jovan. does it means that it is not really a query when I see in Symfony2 'START TRANSACTION'? it just say something like: "all above queries can be processed" (right?) And what about "**COMMIT**"?